# How should I convert a Dataframe full of decimals to floats?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The main problem I have right now is that [DataFrame.quantile() doesn't work with Decimals](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13157).

I can convert my Dataframe to floats by using `df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)`, but this generates a deprecation warning and the suggested replacement `infer_objects()` doesn't work.

As an alternative, I could use `Dataframe.round` on my input data instead of converting them to Decimals. I assume that this should be safe for direct comparisons (I am indexing on a column to subtract two dataframes from each other, e.g. `df1.set_index('Time') - df2.set_index('Time')`) but I can't be certain.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can apply [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) to an entire dataframe:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='float')
```

Comment: The `downcast='float'` doesn't seem to be necessary but I like the df.apply.

Comment: Yup, it' s not a requirement, but it's good practice for large dataframes (since it can save memory).

Comment: This is probably kinda obvious, but it bears mention that the "downcast" option rounds off the decimal to a lower precision so it's not suitable if the full decimal is needed.

Answer (score 7):

Try doing this:

```
df.column_name = df.column_name.astype(float)
```

For reference see [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:

```
for c in df:
    df[c] = pd.to_numeric(df[c])
```